# NHibernate Interceptor - What is it

Tags: nhibernate, configuration, interceptor

What is NHibernate Interceptor, and what purpose does it serve in an application?

Also, [in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx), I learned that using NHibernate makes a desktop application slower at startup, so to avoid this, I need to save the configuration in a file, and later load it from the saved file. How can I do that? I didn't find any examples in that tutorial.

Comment: There are two questions here. Please create individual questions for each issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An interceptor allows you to execute additional functionality when an entity is retrieved / deleted / updated / inserted in the DB ...

[Interceptors article](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/9-interceptors-in-hibernate-orm-framework-an-introducti-1.html)

[Hibernate doc](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html)

[other useful info](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=nhibernate+interceptor)

About making your app slower:
I'd suggest that you only have a look at optimizing start-up time, when it really becomes a problem.

When you build a session-factory, NHibernate will parse all the mappings, and that is an operation that is a bit expensive.  But, as long as you have a limited number of entities, the performance hit isn't that big.
I have never ever had to optimize the initialization of NHibernate, because of slow startup times.

I'd suggest that you first concentrate on the core of your application -the problem you're trying to solve- and afterwards have a look on how you could improve startup performance.
(If you'll ever have to do it).

Answer (score 7):

[Interceptors](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-interceptors), like the name itself says, allows you to intercept NHibernate operations (save/update/delete/load/flush/etc).

A newer, more flexible API to achieve this is the [event system](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-events).

About serializing the configuration, the code is there, it's the class `Effectus.Infrastructure.BootStrapper` which is called at application startup.

Answer (score 4):

An interceptor's dissection series written by me can be found in here 
http://blog.scooletz.com/2011/02/03/nhibernate-interceptor-magic-tricks-pt-1/

hope it helps