# Using nhibernate without default constructors

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I make nhibernate work without default contructors for entities?

Not just for the entity information but also to resolve dependencies like `IUserService` or `ITextParser`

I'm using nhibernate 3.2

Comment: Why are you attaching service dependencies to your entities?

Answer (score 0):

you need to distinguish between constructing an object, and dehydrating it. the default constructors are used for the latter. if you want to have custom constructors, i suggest to create partial classes to use for the mappings and have the custom constructors in other partials.

also, if you want to inject dependencies or implementations while dehydrating an object, you can use [Interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034003/nhibernate-interceptor-what-is-it)

hope, my late evening mumbling helps